# Ошибка десериализации xml ("xmlns" vs "xmlns:xsi")

Tags: c#, xml, сериализация, десериализация

Десерриализую xml вида:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0" >
  <configSections>
    <section name="nameSettings" type="company.Product.Config.module, Config"/>
  </configSections>

   ...

  </configuration>
```

код:

```
protected configuration Deserialize(string filename)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Configuration));                
            serializer.UnknownNode += new
            XmlNodeEventHandler(serializer_UnknownNode);
            serializer.UnknownAttribute += new
            XmlAttributeEventHandler(serializer_UnknownAttribute);

            FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);                
            configuration webConfig;                
            webConfig = (configuration)serializer.Deserialize(fs); // <-- ошибка тут
            fs.Close();    
            return webConfig;
         }
```

ошибка:

[image: System.InvalidOperationException]

Если во второй строке xml-файла заменить  **xmlns** на **xmlns:xsi** чтобы получилось:

```xml
<configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

То проблема исчезает 0_о

xml я менять не могу(такой прилетает) подскажите как мне адаптировать код чтобы не было ошибки.

---

P.S.
валидность xml и с **xmlns** и с  **xmlns:xsi**  проверял на http://www.xmlvalidation.com/ - ошибок не найдено.

Comment: а сильно различаются разбираемые файлы, или они всегда имеют одинаковую структуру? Если бы речь шла о создаваемых классах, я бы говорил что вам не хватает параметров: ` [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0")]`

Comment: @Monomax структура разбираемых файлов будет всегда одинакова, класс(configuration) со всеми полями я уже написал

Comment: тогда вам проще создать классы, и далее дессериализовывать ваши файлы через классы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам отвечу, ошибка оказаласть в классе Configuration

было:

```
 [XmlRootAttribute("configuration", IsNullable = false)]
```

а нужно:

```
 [XmlRootAttribute("configuration", Namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0")]
```